# How to run JarSigner without jdk installed in linux?

Tags: java, jarsigner

I am trying to run the *JarSigner* as process from Java code in a Linux machine where there is no JDK available. Only JRE is available.

I tried copying the *jarsigner* from the bin folder of a JDK installation into the bin folder of the JRE and also the `tool.jar` from the lib of JDK to lib folder of JRE. But it did not work.

**The error message received:**

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.tools.KeyStoreUtil.isSelfSigned(Ljava/security/cert/X509Certificate;)

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jarsigner -keystore "
                    + tempFile.getAbsolutePath()
                    + " -storepass stack -keypass overflow -signedjar "
                    + newbtrpFile2.getName() + " "
                    + newbtrpFile1.getName() + " bogus-cert" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the JarSigner without the JDK.
If you try using the JarSigner standalone, the following Error trace will appear:

```
Error: could not find libjava.dylib
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

This has to do with how the JarSigner works and integrates itself within the Java Runtime Environment.